# Create xpath with key using dom4j

Tags: java, xpath, dom4j

Does anybody know how to automagically get xpath with keys when using dom4j elements?

Let me explain:

Given the following xml I have created a dom4j document.

```
<response>
  <installation>
    <id>0001</cid>
    <code>0000</code>
  </installation>
  <installation>
    <id>0002</cid>
    <code>0078</code>
  </installation>
</response>
```

Looping through the document I can create an xpath for each element using `element.getUniquePath()` or `element.getPath()`

```
/response/installation[1]/code
or
/response/installation/code
```

So far so good, but not quite good enough. Since the order of the objects can never be know in advance I would like to use key in my xpath.

```
 /response/installation[id=0001]/code
```

Now my question is if anybody out there knows how to do this.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know any way to change the strategy behind `getUniquePath` and `getPath`.

If you iterate over elements which are codes you can retrieve the preceding sibling and generate an XPath with that, by retrieving the text content of the `id` tag before the `code` one.

Otherwise this XPath would work: `/response/installation/code[preceding-sibling::id[text()=0002]]`